# Regex to match string in current URL including wild card

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be regex to match part of a URL using JavaScript and also include wildcards?

For example:

match all pages: `/pages/*`

match a page called about: `/pages/about`

match all products that contain the string large: `/products/*large*`

https://jsbin.com/toxemanewe/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Do you mean you want to match URLs that contain wildcards, or you want to put a wildcard in the pattern?

Comment: I want to include a wild card in the pattern

Comment: A wildcard is equivalent to the regexp `.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've did small changes in your code:

```
var patterns = [
  'about',
  'checkout',
  'contact'
];

var str = 'https://myurl.com/page/about/';

for (i=0; i<patterns.length; i++) {

  if ((new RegExp(patterns[i])).test(str)) {
//----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  look here how to instantiate the regex

    console.log('matched pattern: '  +  patterns[i]);
//----------------------------------^^^ look here plus sign instead comma

  }

}
```

I've commented the updates.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As your question asks, the regex's to use for your 3 examples are:-

**/pages/*** - uses .* for anything after '/pages/'

```
/\/pages\/.*/.test(str);
```

**/pages/about** - to match exactly '/pages/about'

```
/\/pages\/about/.test(str);
```

**/products/*large*** - to match '/products/' and then contains 'large'

```
/\/products\/.*(?:large).*/.test(str);
```

and used in your example like

```
var patterns = [
  '/pages/.*',
  '/pages/about',
  '/products/.*(?:large).*'
];

for (i=0; i<patterns.length; i++) {
  if ((new RegExp(patterns[i])).test(window.location.href)) {  
    console.log('matched pattern ' + patterns[i]);
  }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7k7qdwhu/)